# Searching within sublists in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

Note: I am using R5RS

```
(define (found? value L)

  (cond

    ((null? L) #f)

    ((equal? (car L) value) #t)

    (else (found? value (cdr L)))))
```

This is the function I wrote for iterating over a list like `(7 "a" (b (c a) () (d d)))`.

If I call `(found? "a" '(7 "a" (b (c a)) () (d d)))`, it returns `#t`.

But if I call `(found? 'a '(7 "a" (b (c a)) () (d d)))`, it returns `#f`.

I know that if I look for the entire sublist like `(b (c a))`, the function returns true.
But it doesn't work for nested sublist, e.g. `(c a)`.

How can I find the `a` within the sublist `(c a)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an additional `cond` branch for nested lists:

```
(define (found? value lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) #f)
    ((equal? (car lst) value) #t)
    ((list? (car lst))
     (or (found? value (car lst))
         (found? value (cdr lst))))
    (else (found? value (cdr lst)))))
```

Tests:

```
> (found? "a" '(7 "a" (b (c a)) () (d d)))
#t
> (found? 'a '(7 "a" (b (c a)) () (d d)))
#t
```